# Can I have the same image in multiple NextGen galleries?

Tags: gallery, plugin-nextgen-gallery

Is it possible to have the same image in multiple NextGEN galleries without duplicating the image?

For example, let's say I have a gallery called "dogs" and a gallery called "cats".  If I have a picture of a dog and a cat, I'd like to have this in both my "dogs" gallery and my "cat" gallery.  By default, NextGEN creates a new folder for each gallery (e.g. `/wp-content/gallery/dogs`), and either adds uploaded media to the folder, or moves media from `/wp-content/uploads` to the new gallery folder.  I'd like to have only one copy of my dog-and-cat image uploaded to my server.